# Prevent SelectionChanged event during DragDrop WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I'm working on a `WPF` application with `MVVM` pattern using `Telerik` controls.

**Functionality:**

I'm using `telerik:RadListBox` for which a collection is bind at runtime. I can ReOrder the items in the RadListBox.

**Issue:**

When i `DragDrop` items within `RadListBox` after `DragLeave` event the `SelectionChanged` event gets fired.

**XAML:**

```
<telerik:RadListBox x:Name="lstMarketSeries" ItemsSource="{Binding MarketSeriesCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DraggableListBoxItem}" DragLeave="lstMarketSeries_DragLeave" SelectionMode="Extended"  telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" SelectionChanged="MarketSeriesCommit_SelectionChanged">
</telerik:RadListBox>
```

**XAML.cs:**

```
private void MarketSeriesCommit_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
 {

 }

private void lstMarketSeries_DragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
 {        

 }
```

Is there any way that i can restrict the SelectionChanged event getting fired after `DragLeave` event?

Comment: How about not adding the handler? Will that work for you?

Comment: @tgpdyk : No, i need the handler to manipulate some values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is a good idea to prevent the selection event hadler to fire. But you can try to add the flag IsInDrag(boolean) and manage this during the darag/drop action(true on start dragging and false when you enter the final selection changed handler), in addition when you entering the SelectionChanged event handler and the flag is true you set this false and leave the handler(in addition you can set the handle property of the SelectionChangedEventArgs to true) that's all.

Regards.